# Can not find symbols in latex

Tags: pdf

I am new in latex and I need to express the following symbols:

```
&, &&, ^, | , || , <, <=, >, >= , == , != , %
```

When I write them in that way, nothing happens on the document. Please help.

best regards,

Comment: You can start from http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf and from making sure you handle correctly math delimiters.

Comment: See [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Comment: Are the symbols used in program code? Then package `listings` or verbatim mode helps.

Comment: @egreg It is not clear that these should be math symbols. They look rather like operators of a programming language.

Answer (score 5):

The symbols can be set in verbatim mode, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb|&|  & bitwise and\\
  \verb|&&| & logical and\\
  \verb|^|  & bitwise xor\\
  \verb+|+  & bitwise or\\
  \verb+||+ & logical or\\
  \verb|<|  & less than\\
  \verb|<=| & less than or equal to\\
  \verb|>|  & greater than\\
  \verb|>=| & greater than or equal to\\
  \verb|==| & equal to\\
  \verb|!=| & not equal to\\
  \verb|%|  & modulo\\
  \verb|~|  & bitwise not\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Program code can also be set via package [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

Answer (score 1):

You should put this in an equation environment, e.g.:

```
\begin{equation} 
 a <= b | c
\end{equation}
```

In this case your equation gets a number. To avoid this, do the following:

```
\begin{equation*} 
 a <= b | c
\end{equation*}
```

But if you want to write for example a simple % in your text, you can do it like this:

```
\%
```

Answer (score 1):

Helping myself with the [guide](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) I linked in my comment above, here is a list of symbols of yours that you can render, inside or outside the math delimiters, not needing AMS-LaTeX packages or any other. The following code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

a \& b \% c \textasciicircum{} d

\[
e \vert f | g < h \le i \ge j > k \ne l = m
\]

Also: $\|n\|$.

The following unescaped percent produces a comment % indeed this text does not show

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: screenshot of output]

Check in the manual how to use more specific or sophisticated symbols provided by several dedicated packages.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols like `+`, `-`, `||`, `<`, `>` would work without the dollar symbols.

The more critical symbols and some good practices of using it are explained and suggested as follows:

1. For using ampersand (`&`) symbol, use backslash (`\`) before the symbol. The correct way of including the ampersand symbol in the document is as follows: `\&`.
2. Any mathematical/greek symbols should be enclosed within `$ $`. For this, add `\usepackage{amsmath}`.
   For example: `$+$`, `$-$` etc.
   **Note:** it's a good practice to enclose any used alphabets and mathematical symbols within dollar symbols, like: `$a$` and `$+$`.
3. For using the symbols percentage (`%`) and underscore (`_`), you need to add backslash (`\`) just before the symbol. The same is illustrated as follows.
   Suppose you want to write 99% and latex_symb. The correct way of writing the aforementioned words is as follows: `77\%`, `latex\_symb`.  (1)
   This will produce the output with no errors.
   **Note:** moreover, the use of dollar symbols in statement (1) is a good practice. This practice is optional. But using this, it will be efficient for differentiating the normal text and used mathematical words. The same is explained as follows, like this: `$77\%$, $latex\_symb$`.

Additionally, If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a `\` in front of the character. For example, `\$` will produce $ in your output.

Hope this helps. Thank You.

Comment: you should click on tick to accept the best answer and upvote for others which helped you @user3097712.

Answer (score 1):

You may try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html - just draw the symbol you are looking for and the applet there will give you the required packages (if necessary) as well as the code for the symbol...